# Using positions on two text objects

Tags: html, css

We have a requirement for the main text shown on the main image (Title 1) to be shown in the same position in the relevant thumbnail to the right.

[image]

For example, the styling we're using on 'Title 1' is:

```
position: absolute;
left: 25%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 999;
letter-spacing: -2px;
font-weight: 900;
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
```

This is showing correctly in the main image, but isn't showing correctly in the relevant thumbnail (it's using exactly the same style), the text is shown to the right of the image instead. Like this:

[image]

Title 1 might be centered at the top while Title 2 might be rotated in the centre vertically. Just need the main text to match in the thumbnail

This isn't working correctly for the thumbnail but it is showing where we want it on the main image.

Is there a better way to do this than using position: absolute, left and top?

HTML is

```html
    <div id="shopmain1" style="background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg&text=+); position: relative; width:100%; height:100%; background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0px 0px;">        
     <div id="shop_textlayer1" style="position: absolute; left: 25%; margin-top:0; transform: rotate(0deg); width: 100%;color: #000000;"><span class="shop_textlayer1_span">Title 1</span></div>  
    </div>

    <div class="shop_thumb item" id="thumb1" onclick="shopsetmainimage(1)" style="background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.jpg&text=+);">
        <div class="textOverlay thumb" id="shop_textlayer1" style="position: absolute; left: 25%; margin-top:0; transform: rotate(0deg); width: 100%;color: #000000;"><span class="shop_textlayer1_span">Title 1</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="shop_thumb item" id="thumb2" onclick="shopsetmainimage(2)" style="background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.jpg&text=+);">
        <div class="textOverlay thumb" id="shop_textlayer2" style="position: absolute; left: 10%; margin-top:15%; transform: rotate(45deg); width: 100%;color: #000000;"><span class="shop_textlayer1_span">Title 2</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="shop_thumb item" id="thumb3" onclick="shopsetmainimage(3)" style="background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.jpg&text=+);">
        <div class="textOverlay thumb" id="shop_textlayer3" style="position: absolute; left: 25%; margin-top:80%; transform: rotate(0deg); width: 100%;color: #000000;"><span class="shop_textlayer1_span">Title 3</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="shop_thumb item" id="thumb4" onclick="shopsetmainimage(4)" style="background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.jpg&text=+);">
        <div class="textOverlay thumb" id="shop_textlayer4" style="position: absolute; left: 105%; margin-top:15%; transform: rotate(90deg); width: 100%;color: #000000;"><span class="shop_textlayer1_span">Title 4</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please attach all the codes needed to reproduce the issue

Comment: It looks like you've gotten the Title 4 thumbnail to behave like you're wanting the Title 1 thumbnail to. Have you tried replicating what you're using for that one?

Comment: Avoid using [*magic numbers*](https://css-tricks.com/magic-numbers-in-css/) in CSS. Try bigger titles and you will find problems in all scenarios. Search for "css text centering" and you will find a lot of information.

Answer (score 0):

to position TITLE1 in the top center position. try to use this CSS properties:

```
.top-center{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 999;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

and for position it in the center/center with rotated it, use:

```
.center-center{
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,50%) rotate(90deg);
    z-index: 999;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```